# MutableLiveData observes while there is no change in data

Tags: android, android-livedata

I have experienced a weird behavior of MutableLiveData objects as they are sometimes observed continuously even without change in the data in it.
As of my knowledge it should be observed only when it comes to active state from inactive state or the data in it has been modified.

In my Viewmodel:

```
val liveData = MutableLiveData<Any>()
```

In fragment:

```
 viewModel.liveData.observe(this, Observer { response -> 
//stuff to do and it is called continuously 
           }
        })
```

Can you help me understand this behavior or Is there any way to avoid this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you calling `liveData.value` recursively ?

Comment: No, only once @Jeel Vankhede

Comment: One more question, are you observing it inside `onResume()`? if yes then don't, move it to `onCreate()` of fragment.

Comment: Observing it in onCreate() of fragment@JeelVankhede

Answer (score 0):

You are observing changes for `Any` class, try using a different class may be a custom class.

```
val liveData = MutableLiveData<SomeOtherClass>()
```

and then observe this like you do.

Comment: Yes, i have done this too, this is random. Only some objects are observed, not all.